# Simple propability issue

Tags: probability

I have a simple problem:
I have 16 kitties. There is 1/2 chance to get a male and 1/2 chance to get a female.
What is the probability to get at least a female?

[image]

Then, if 10 kitties die, what is the new probability to get a female?

I would appreciate any help on this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you see *at least one*, all you have to do is get the probability of getting none and get its complement. By this I mean:

$$P(\text{at least 1 female})=1-P(\text{no females})$$

Should make sense; all other combinations aside from the no females one will have at least 1 female. The probability of having only males is:

$$P(\text{no females})=P(\text{16 males})=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{16}$$

It's like flipping coins. Probability of $1$ head is $\frac12$, two will be $\frac12 \times \frac12 = (\frac12)^2$, etc.

Anyway, we've got our answer:
$$P(\text{at least 1 female})=1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{16}\approx 99.9847\%$$

After $10$ die (`:(`), it's the same exact thing except you're left with 6. Hence, instead of $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{16}$, you'll do $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{6}$:

$$P(\text{at least 1 female})=1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{6}=98.4375\%$$

Comment: thanks a lot for this explanations!

Comment: @superrache Any time~.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of getting at least one female is the same as one minus the probability of not getting a female.

The probability of getting all males is simply $\frac{1}{2^{16}}$, so you want $1-\frac{1}{2^{16}}$.

This is a particular case of binomial distribution that doesn't require the formula $\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{(n-k)}$. For $k$ males/females of $n$ kittens total, you'd need that formula.

Not sure what you mean by "if 10 kittens die" though. If you mean what is the probability that after 10 die, you're still left with a female kitten, then it's the exact same thing as assuming those kittens were never born: $1-\frac{1}{2^{6}}$. Without loss of generality, you assume the last 10 kittens that were born die, and since they're dead, whether they were male or female doesn't matter.

If that wasn't what you meant, do let me know so I can fix my answer.

Comment: great thanks for your answer, you are right!